# Bootstrap Multi Select With Autocomplete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, multi-select, dropdown

I am using silviomoreto bootstrap-multi-select in my entire application. I have came across one requirement where the resultset has million of records. The way we want to present on the browser is - The user will be shown 20-25 entries and when the user will start typing in the live search box an ajax call will be made and an autocomplete option box will be shown as per the string filled by the user.

Is there any plugin already available for the same or any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Happy Learning

Answer (score 1):

as I understand,I think this plugin will be useful for you.

**[Jquery Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect/)**

Comment: How? I am looking for something that has the support for showing dropdowns and making ajax call as well if the element is not available in the rendered element search.